# Knockout JS: object always returns undefined, even when should have values

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout and am still trying to understand how it works. I have this function that should be returning data from an ajax call but when I try to get the values the object is saying it is undefined.

My model where the data is undefined:

```
    function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Organization = ko.observable();
    self.App = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.Deployed = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.EngagementSolutions = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.MS = ko.observable();


   self.ActiveEngagements = ko.computed(function () {
        var ActiveEngagements = 0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.EngagementSolutions(), function (item) {
            if (item.IsActive) {
                ActiveEngagements++;
            }
        });
        return ActiveEngagements;
    });
    self.TicketCount = ko.computed(function () {
        console.log(self.Organization.UniqueICount);
        var uniqueOpenICount = (self.Organization.UniqueOpenICount === "undefined" ? self.Organization.UniqueOpenICount : 0);
        var uniqueICount = (self.Organization.UniqueICount === "undefined" ? self.Organization.UniqueICount : 0);
        console.log(uniqueOpenICount + " / " + uniqueICount);
        return uniqueOpenICount + " / " + uniqueICount;
    });
```

My function where the values are populating the object:

```
    function SucessFunction(data) {
    console.log(data.Organizations[0].UniqueICount);

        var newOrganization = new OrganizationObject();
        newOrganization.UniqueICount = data.Organizations[0].UniqueICount;
        newOrganization.UniqueOpenICount = data.Organizations[0].UniqueOpenICount;

        console.log(newOrganization);
        viewModel.Organization = newOrganization;
        console.log(viewModel.Organization);
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: I suggest working through some of the KO tutorials on the site and elsewhere, there are some fundamentals that you're not currently getting, based on the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `observable` incorrectly. KO's observables are *functions*.

You set their value by calling them with a new value as an argument:

```
viewModel.Organization(newOrganization);
```

not

```
viewModel.Organization = newOrganization; // Not this
```

You get their value by calling them without an argument:

```
console.log(viewModel.Organization());
// -------------------------------^^
```

not

```
console.log(viewModel.Organization);      // Not this
```

Primarily, the way you're misusing it will cause the computed not to work correctly and the view not to update.

There are a few other problems as well:

- When you start using the observable correctly, you'll also need to update the computed's code not only to get its value correctly, but to allow for the fact that it starts off being `undefined`, which means you can't read those subordinate properties from it.
- You're comparing property values with `"undefined"`. My guess is you probably meant to compare their **type** with `"undefined"` or compare their value to `undefined`. But comparing their value with `"undefined"` will give you `false` unless, of course, they actually contain the **string** `"undefined"`.
- There are also some curly brace and parentheses mismatches, at least in the code in the question.

Here's a rough update, but it's not meant to do all the work, just to point you in the right direction:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Organization = ko.observable();

    self.TicketCount = ko.computed(function() {
        // *** Reading the value, using a local variable to remember it during this call,
        // branching if we don't have one y et
        var organization = self.Organization();
        if (!organization) {
            // We don't have one yet
            return "-/-";
        }
        console.log(organization.UniqueICount);
        // *** Handling undefined by values via ||
        var uniqueOpenICount = organization.UniqueOpenICount || 0;
        var uniqueICount = organization.UniqueICount || 0;
        console.log(uniqueOpenICount + " / " + uniqueICount); // *** Beware that 0/0 is NaN, and n/0 is Infinity, so
        return uniqueOpenICount + " / " + uniqueICount;       // *** ...you probably want more logic here
    });
}

function SucessFunction(data) {
    console.log(data.Organizations[0].UniqueICount);

    var newOrganization = new OrganizationObject();
    newOrganization.UniqueICount = data.Organizations[0].UniqueICount;
    newOrganization.UniqueOpenICount = data.Organizations[0].UniqueOpenICount;

    console.log(newOrganization);
    // *** Note setting it via call
    viewModel.Organization(newOrganization);
    // *** Note getting it via call
    console.log(viewModel.Organization());
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added to the question that this isn't the only data being obtained by this function. When I use `viewModel.Organization(newOrganization);` it overwrites the rest of the data needed in this function that is working

Comment: @WorkHardWork: The fundamental issue is unchanged though: You're using `observable` incorrectly. The details are a matter of debugging.